# Fermat Test for compositeness, how many bases needed?

Tags: number-theory, primality-test

The Fermat Test base $a$ checks for a number $n$ whether or not $(a,n) = 1$ and $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

If for some base $a$, $n$ does not pass this test then we know $n$ is composite. But, realistically, how many values of $a\geq 2$ do we need to test?

Clearly, due to checking for the greatest common divisor we never need $\sqrt n < a$ but can we decrease this bound? Is there a worst case scenario where a composite number only fails the test for $a = \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$?

Comment: If the number has no special form, even a single test gives a high probability. Carmichael numbers however pass every base that is coprime to the given number. The strong probable prime test is much better, giving a probability of $(\frac{1}{4})^N$ that the number is prime if it passes $N$ tests with distinct random bases.

Comment: @Peter I'm sorry I should have been more clear. I am assuming here that the number is not a Carmichael number. So we have a composite, non-Carmichael $n$ and I'm interested in how many bases we may need to check

Comment: Do you mean the worst-case-scenario ?

Comment: @Peter yes, I am writing a program to perform this test and it's a bit slow, so I wanted to know if I could possibly make the test shorter by not checking everything

Comment: Even non-Carmichael numbers can be strong pseudoprime to many bases.

Comment: @Peter I guess that $\sqrt{n}$ is probably the best general bound then?

Comment: I have no clue what the best general bound is, but $\sqrt{n}$ should be far too large.

Comment: This depends on how you select the $a$s to be tested. The number of unreliable witnesses can be quite high. Consider the case of $n=pq$ with two primes $p,q$ such that $q=2p-1$ and therefore $q-1=2(p-1)$. Because $n-1\equiv p-1\pmod{q-1}$ and $n-1\equiv q-1\pmod{p-1}$ we see that $a^{n-1}$ is automatically congruent to $1$ modulo $p$ (unless $p\mid a$). And also $a^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod q$ if $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $q$. This means that almost one half of the choices $a$ pass the test. For example, with $n=19\cdot37=703$, $324$ out of $702$ choices of $a$ give $a^{702}\equiv1\pmod{703}$.

Comment: (cont'd) So if you are unlucky with your choices... May be you are planning on trying consecutive $a$s? That should help a lot. In the above example: Probably it is known how long the runs of consecutive quadratic residues can be. I can prove something like $O(q^{1/2}\log q)$ estimating incomplete character sums with Vinogradov's method. I'm not an expert on this. Hopefully one shows up.

Comment: And, with $n=703$ it suffices to go up to $a=2$ :-) Also, modulo $37$ the longest runs of consecutive quadratic residues have length four (two such runs actually one negative of the other because $-1$ is a QR modulo $37$). This means that at least one $a$ out of any five consecutive integers proves compositeness of $703$.